# Ошибка "g++ not available. Глубокое обучение

Tags: python, keras

При попытке запустить файл python получаю ошибку, запуск обучения идёт, но крайне долго.

```
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda: `conda install m2w64-toolchain`
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
```

Устанавливать то , что предлагает пробовал - не помогает. 
Может кто сталкивался.
`Keras` и `Theano` устанавливал и через `pip` и через `conda`

Comment: А команду из совета в 1 строке пробовали? Ну или отдельно в систему   поставить g++?

Comment: Я же написал, пробовал , в систему тоже ставил. У меня подозрение, что дело в kerax, который уже несколько раз переустановил

Comment: О какой OS идет речь?

Comment: Извините не уточнил - windows

Comment: @VladTeryoshin, `conda install mingw` - mingw ставить пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал , после этого вообще запуска не происходит, вылетает несколько исключений и ошибок

Comment: На винде C/CXX должен собираться с помощью MSVC в идеале.Так же создатели библиотеки обычно предоставляют собранные бинарники в виде колес.Попробуйте `pip install wheel`-так у вас будет возможность использовать уже собранные библиотеки под вашу ОС (если создатели их предоставили). Если позарез надо gcc и его компиляторы/сборщики, то можете воспользоваться[TDM-GCC](tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/),однако, это не волшебная таблетка-она вас не спасет от настройки-вам так или иначе придется изучать мануал по тому, как собрать библиотеку на вашей ОС.Еще можно попытать счастья на lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs

Comment: "Пробовал , после этого вообще запуска не происходит, вылетает несколько исключений и ошибок" - и какие конкретно ошибки?